# Is there any front-end image recognition JS library?

Tags: javascript, html, image-recognition

If I need to turn on a camera using front-end webpage, scan an image and see if target image matches pre-defined image. if so, throw a web event.

Is there a JS library doing the job?

thanks

Comment: Should it work offline? For instance, let's say I load your webpage and then board a plane with no WiFi.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul not really needed. I just need it to be front-end only

Comment: Do you have any requirement for the server-side, then? Self-hosted? No budget limit?

Comment: no specific requirements. it could be hosted on github.io or any front-end service provider.  I have budget, but limit is unknown for now.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember two js libraries Tenserflow  &  tracking JS. Both can do like webcam tracking, real-time color tracking, face detection etc.

Comment: can tracking.js do image recognition? like, compare similarity between 2 image?

Answer (score 1):

A little older library is https://github.com/timhuff/canvas-phash.
It's a library that uses [phash](https://www.phash.org/) 
 to detect how similar images are.